# Checking if all modules that will be required are available on PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I have written a large system in Python that I now want to distribute to some colleagues. There are a few folders that need to be added to PYTHONPATH for all of my modules (files) to be found. I am looking for a way to give them sane error messages if they have not setup their PYTHONPATH correctly. Say the structure is:

```
ParentModule
  calls Child
     calls GrandChild
        calls MyModule
```

If they run ParentModule, it could be running for a long time before it ever ends up in GrandChild and needs MyModule, and if MyModule's directory is not on PYTHONPATH, it will crash complaining that it can't find MyModule. I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
for file in (all files that could ever be reached from here):
  if all modules needed by 'file' are not available
    print "error: Please make sure your PYTHONPATH points to x,y, and z"
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Are the import so dynamic that you cannot enumerate them for each release of your program and check them statically?

Comment: Please give an example of how `Child`, `GrandChild`, and `MyModule` are actually used.

Comment: The problem with `for file in (all files that could ever be reached from here):` is that any file could potentially be reached from anywhere :P. Unless you mean something more specific when you say "reached" and "called".

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your main module I would just try to import all of the modules your program depends on, and wrap it in a try/except for printing your sane error if any of the import statements fail:

```
import sys
try:
    import Child
    import GrandChild
    import MyModule
except ImportError:
    print "Error: Please make sure your PYTHONPATH points to x, y, and z"
    sys.exit(1)

# current module contents
```

Comment: Is there a way to do:
myModule = "Child";
import myModule
? Or do the keywords after 'import' have to be static/literals?

Comment: If you want to import a module by a dynamic variable name, you can use `__import__(name)` or the `imp` module. You could also do `eval('import ' + name)`, thought that's frowned upon for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're "calling" `Child`, `GrandChild`, and `MyModule`, this should happen automatically.

If by "call" you mean `import`, and you're doing your imports at the type of the module, as is conventional, then all of the import chaining will happen automatically on the import of the parent module. So if a downstream import is unavailable, then you'll get an `ImportError` when you import the `ParentModule`. If you're "calling" the scripts, by say, executing them in a subprocess, then no I don't think there's an easy way to ensure the availability of modules, given the totally dynamic nature of what you're doing. Similarly if you're doing totally dynamic imports. This is one of the down sides to dynamic programming in general - there's often no rigorous way to ensure that things will be the way you intended them to be.

Edit:

You could definitely do something heuristic like @F.J. suggests though.